# Multiple threads in Java for resolving deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, dining-philosopher

I'm having trouble with the deadlock problem with threads. It seems the problem is about how threads work. I have 2 questions here.

1. Although I created 5 threads and start them, not all of them call `run()`. It's random but I don't know why.
2. There's a problem with the `while()` in main method, my code keeps running unlimited even I set the end condition.

It would be so great if you can help me.

Here my class Chopstick

```java
static class Chopstick {
    public Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);

    void grab() {
        try {
            mutex.acquire();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    void release() {
        mutex.release();
    }
}
```

Here my class Philosopher (aka Thread). I used resources hierarchy solution that the odd philosopher needs to pick up the left chopstick first and then the right one, the even picks up the right.

```java
static class Philosopher extends Thread {
    public boolean eaten = false;
    public int number;
    public Chopstick leftChopstick;
    public Chopstick rightChopstick;
    public Philosopher(int number, Chopstick leftChopstick, Chopstick rightChopstick) {
        this.number = number;
        this.leftChopstick = leftChopstick;
        this.rightChopstick = rightChopstick;
    }
    public void run() {
        int phils=5;
        while (true) {
            if (number % 2 == 1) {
                leftChopstick.grab();
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + number  + " grabs chopstick " + number);
                rightChopstick.grab();
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + number  + " grabs chopstick " + (number+1)%phils);
                eat();
                leftChopstick.release();
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + number  + " releases chopstick " + number );
                rightChopstick.release();
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + number  + " releases chopstick " +(number+1)%phils);
            } else {
                leftChopstick.grab();
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + number  + " grabs chopstick " + (number+1)%phils);
                rightChopstick.grab();
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + number  + " grabs chopstick " + number );
                eat();
                leftChopstick.release();
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + number  + " releases chopstick " + (number+1)%phils);
                rightChopstick.release();
                System.out.println("Philosopher " + number  + " releases chopstick " + number );
            }
        }
    }
    void eat() {
        try {
            int sleepTime = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 1000);
            System.out.println("Philosopher " + number + " eats for " + sleepTime+"s");
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

And my main class:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Test {
    static int number = 5;
    static Philosopher phils[] = new Philosopher[number];
    static Chopstick chopstick[] = new Chopstick[number]; 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            chopstick[i] = new Chopstick();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                phils[i] = new Philosopher(i, chopstick[(i + 1) % number], chopstick[i]);
            } else {
                phils[i] = new Philosopher(i, chopstick[i], chopstick[(i + 1) % number]);
            }
            phils[i].start();
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                boolean isAllEaten = true;
                for (Philosopher p : phils) {
                    if (!p.eaten) {
                        isAllEaten = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isAllEaten) {
                    System.out.println("Everyone Eats");
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Exit The Program!");
        System.exit(0);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your `break` statements only break out of the inner loop. There is nothing to stop the outer `while` loop from running forever.

Comment: @user207421 There's a `break` in `if` too.

Comment: As an aside, `Philosopher` should not `extends Thread`, it should `implement Runnable`, and then you should either create a thread wrapping that runnable and start that thread, or submit the runnabe to an executor.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I see. I'll try this. But when I `start()` all 5 Philosopher, who would `run()` first? It means who would be hungry and pick up chopstick first. I can see a randomness here by running those code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can see that there are 2 ways to create multiple threads in Java: `extends Thread` and `implements Runnable`. Can I have the reason why using `Runnable` is better?

Comment: Being able to extend `Thread` is - IMHO - a historic mistake in Java. You need to separate concerns, your `Philospher` is not a thread (it doesn't do low-level management of execution, priority, etc), it is an action that can *run* on a dedicated Thread, the current thread, on a thread pool managed by an executor, etc.

Comment: As an aside, there are more than two ways to create multiple threads in Java. The preferred ways these days is to use executor services and/or fork/join pools.

Comment: In any case, as to order, scheduling of a thread to get CPU time is left to the operating system and is largely non-deterministic. If you want them to run in a specific order, you need to do that explicitly with higher level synchronization constructs.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've searched before and most of web said that a philosopher is like a thread since 5 philosophers can act at the same time (such as pick up left chopstick) and they're shared resources that are chopsticks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I understand that threads would `run()` randomly even they're all `start()`. I dont wanna set priority here because the solution I chose to resolve deadlock is avoiding a circular wait.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Back to the life, my solution is that the odd philosopher needs to pick up the left chopstick first and then the right one, the even picks up the right. Supposed I have `P1`-`P5` and `C1`-`C5`. `C1` is between `P1` and `P5`. If all philosophers get hungry, `P5` would eat while `P1` and `P2` were fighting for `C2`, so do `P3`, `P4`. How can I resolve the conflicts between them? I understand there's an easier resource hierarchy solution that we can force 4 philosophers to pick up the left chopsticks and the 5th pick up the right one. But I have no choice.